# Site SSL content issue on Firefox and IE

Tags: asp.net, security, ssl

My site is no securing the online transactions.  I found the ssl setting and turned it on, but it still does not appear to be working properly.  Below are some images for IE and Firefox.  Although the https is present, it does not appear to be securing the site. This is mainly issue credit card information page. How to solve this.

image below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is made up of secure and insecure content. Firefox is blocking the insecure stuff.

For example, your page is served from `https://www.example.com/index.html`, but some of the content within it it is served from `http://www.example.com/images`. Firefox will block the content from the second location. That's what the message in your image says.

You should serve all your content through a secure channel. i.e. serve everything from `https://www.example.com`

Comment: @hello Mike, how to do this, you meant all pages should make as https

Comment: Thanks for help immediately, it is very help full comments.

Comment: I have changed all http to https on my entire site but i have got same SSL problem could you please help me immediatly

Comment: @Sajith I'd guess you've probably missed something, but you haven't posted any code or a link to the site so I can't confirm that, or  suggest where to look.

Comment: I have rechecked everything  there has no containing http... site working locally fine with out SSL problem but when i upload live site which will get same SSL problem on Firefox.

Comment: Well, without  link to the site, there's nothing more I can do.

Comment: Visiting `https://www.opalevents.org` redirects to `http://www.opalevents.org`, so I cannot replicate the problem. A look at the page source that is delivered reveals some 24 images and other resources referenced on `http://www.opalevents.org`. I can't tell how that is generated, so maybe on the secure version it uses the secure URL - maybe not. BTW Why are you loading `basic.css` three times?

Comment: i can run in this project Local Server with out but this same code could not work live site do you have any idea

Comment: I have one doubts, If there is in call External link on my site eg: http://www.yourStore.com/ which is not https. How to solve this or is there any cause of the problem SSL